# Ubuntu Linux: terminal limits the output when I get the full Twitter Streaming API

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, console, terminal

I have this python script that outputs the Twitter Stream to my terminal console. Now here is the interesting thing:
* On snowleopard I get all the data I want.
* On Ubuntu (my pc) this data is limited and older data is deleted.

Both terminal consoles operate in Bash, so it has to be an OS thing presumably.

My question is: how do I turn this off? I want to leave my computer on for a week to capture around 1 or 2 gigabytes of data, for my bachelor thesis!

Comment: [I've always been against the greetings and salutations (along with other extraneous clutter) in questions for a number of reasons...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/179891)

Comment: you don't want this data in your terminal buffer, but on your hard drive. Especially if you want to keep the data for your thesis. Generally this question appears more appropriate for http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ah thanks, the reason I posted it here is because:
1. I have an account on this site and as you can see on my account, I'm quite new with asking questions.
2. If it turned out to be ANYTHING programming related, I'd know people here could switch really fast between domains of knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect the output to file using `>` or `>>`.
say

`$ cmd > filename.txt`

that will put all the content in the filename.txt, also you can redirect the errors using `2>error.txt`.

```
Edit -> profile preference -> Scrolling -> check on unlimited
```

just in case if you want it to on the console.
But i will recommend using file redirection and process the file later.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also avoid doing this with a terminal, but to answer the question directly:

- right click on the terminal window
- profiles
- profile preferences
- scolling
- scollback: unlimited

It's better though to redirect to a file, then access that file.  "tail -f" is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tee(1)`:

```
man tee
command | tee outputfile
```

You could also use `nohup(1)` together with `tail(1)` (if you really need the output in stdout).

```
nohup command &
tail -f nohup.out
```